# SQL Select column with maximum value in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like this:

```
Name  Group   Value
A     1       0
B     1       2
C     1       5
D     2       6
E     2       0
F     3       3
```

I want to select the name with the maximum value within each group. For example, there are 3 groups, so the result would be:

```
Name
C     (because it has the maximum value (5) within group 1)
D     (because it has the maximum value (6) within group 2)
F     (because it has the maximum value (3) within group 3)
```

I tried writing something like this:

```
SELECT name FROM table
WHERE value = (SELECT max(value) FROM table)
GROUP BY group
```

But max(value) returns the global maximum value of the whole table (like (6) in this example). How do I fix this?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags

Comment: If it's not MySQL or Access have a look at `RANK`

Comment: It's SQL Server. Just added it back.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here are some of them:

rextester for all of these: http://rextester.com/DTWB67044

`max()` [**`over()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) version:

```
with cte as (
  select *, MaxValue = max([Value]) over (partition by [Group])
  from t
)
select Name
from cte
where [Value] = MaxValue;
```

`inner join` version:

```
select t.Name
from t
  inner join (
    select MaxValue=max(value), [Group]
    from t
    group by [Group]
    ) as m
      on t.[Group] = m.[Group]
     and t.[Value] = m.MaxValue;
```

[**`cross apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) version:

```
select t.Name
from t
  cross apply (
    select top 1
        [Value]
      from t as i
      where i.[Group] = t.[Group]
      order by i.[Value] desc
     ) as x
  where t.[Value] = x.[Value];
```

---

If you will only be returning one value per group, these work as well:

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
with cte as (
select *, rn = row_number() over (partition by [Group] order by [Value] desc)
from t
)
select Name
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

**[`top with ties`](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** version:

```
select top 1 with ties 
  t.Name
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by [Group] order by [Value] desc);
```

Comment: This is great. Which one is the fastest/best for large data set?

Comment: Are you returning all rows with the maximum value for each group, or just one row with the maximum value for each group? In general, I would recommend the first one from each set above.

Comment: It is exactly as in your rextester example. Just the Names for all rows with the maximum value in each group. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are sort of close.  You need a correlated subquery instead of aggregation in the outer query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE value = (SELECT max(t2.value) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.group = t.group);
```

This is standard SQL and will work in any database.  You can just select `name` if that is all you want, but I figure the `group` would also be useful.

In most databases, you would use `row_number()` for this purpose.

In SQL Server, it would be more typical to do:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by group order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If there are ties (for the maximum), this returns exactly one row (often what is desired).  If you want all such rows, use `rank()` or `dense_rank()` instead.

Comment: Is there an extra parenthesis in your SQL Server Example? I can't get it to work.

Comment: @user3685285 missing one before `partition`

Answer (score 1):

[Gordon's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff) solution appliead to an example from [user3685285](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3685285/user3685285):

`SELECT t.Name
FROM table t
WHERE Value = (SELECT max(tt.Value)
               FROM table tt
               WHERE tt.Group = t.Group);`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the desired output.

```
Select name, max(value) from table group by group order by group
```

Output:

```
C | 5
D | 6
F | 3
```

Comment: It would be nice if it was this simple, but it doesn't work or make sense to me. Can someone validate or invalidate this answer?

Comment: You could validate it by running. But I'm sure about my approach. I even executed it.

Comment: I'd love for your answer to be correct, but the query doesn't even run for me. This is MS SQL Server. If two people say that it works for them, then maybe I'll take another look, but so far it doesn't make sense for me.

Comment: This doesn't work in sql server, it won't pass syntax check let alone provide correct results. http://rextester.com/IPAX86426

Comment: I just made a small typo change. I've ran this on a mysql & sqlite server. Runs on both.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using mysql or sqlite. I'm using SQL Server.