# Google Spreadsheets: How to query countries with max population by continent?

Tags: google-sheets, google-query-language

Let's say I have a table with the columns country, continent and population.

How can I use the QUERY function in Google Spreadsheets to select, for each continent, only the country with the highest population?

In regular SQL I think I'd use HAVING, but this doesn't seem to be an option here.

[image]

Comment: Looking at an answer like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42280491/sql-select-column-with-maximum-value-in-another-column it boils down to two approaches in SQL either
(1) Number the rows in each group in descending order of population
(2) Discard row numbers <>1
or
(1) Find maximum population in each group
(2) Join original table to table of maximums on population.
It seems to me that although TheMaster's solution doesn't explicitly use a query it still uses a SQL-like method (as does mine although more laboriously) and is in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
=SORTN(SORT(G:J,4,0),2^99,2,3,0)
```

- SORT by population in descending order,if not done already
- Remove Duplicates with SORTN

Comment: `SORTN` usage is beautiful!

Comment: @Max Thanks. Investing time in this forgotten function paid off:)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more appropriate to say `=SORTN(SORT(G2:J,4,0),2^99,2,3,0)`. I do agree that it is an extremely elegant and desirable answer, but it doesn't actually answer the question. The OP asked for a solution using the `QUERY` command.

Comment: @Tedinoz It's not possible with query 0.7.

Comment: @TheMaster I _do_ see what you mean about [query 0.7](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#options) (I think. An expert, I am not!). But then, what do you make of Tom Sharpe's answer?

Comment: @TheMaster Actually, strike that comment. Tom Sharpe's answer is ingenious, but I acknowledge that it is not a classic _SQL-like_ query statement.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a helper column, say K with:

```
=if(maxifs(J:J,I:I,I2)=J2,"#","")
```

in K2 and copied down to suit, then:

```
=query(G:K,"select I,H,J where K is not NULL")
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions (both a bit long) where I've got Rank, Country and Continent in columns A, B and C (sorry it would have taken me too long to type in the populations)

To get a list in descending order of rank:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(filter(C:C,C:C<>"")),
vlookup(Query(A:C,"select min(A) where A is not null group by C order by min(A) label min(A) 'Rank'"),A:C,2,false)})
```

To get a list in alphabetical order of continent:

```
=ArrayFormula({Query(A:C,"select C,min(A) where A is not null group by C label min(A) 'Rank'"),
vlookup(Query(A:C,"select min(A) where A is not null group by C label min(A) 'Rank'"),A:C,2,false)})
```

Although the list (I imagine) would go all the way down to Vatican City (pop about 1,000) most countries have at least several thousand inhabitants so I guess ties are pretty unlikely :-)

[image]

---

**UPDATE** - with population data
[image]

Comment: Tom's answer works with population data. 1) Descending rank:`=ArrayFormula({unique(filter(I:I,I:I<>"")),
vlookup(Query(G:J,"select min(G) where G is not null group by I order by min(G) label min(G) 'Rank'"),G:J,2,false),vlookup(Query(G:J,"select min(G) where G is not null group by I order by min(G) label min(G) 'Rank'"),G:J,4,false)})`.

Comment: Tom's answer works with population data. 2) Alpha by continent:`=ArrayFormula({Query(G:J,"select I,min(G) where G is not null group by I label min(G) 'Rank'"),
vlookup(Query(G:J,"select min(G) where G is not null group by I label min(G) 'Rank'"),G:J,2,false),vlookup(Query(G:J,"select min(G) where G is not null group by I label min(G) 'Rank'"),G:J,4,false)})`

Answer (score -1):

In QUERY method Select Continent, maximum of the population and need to group by Continent:

```
=QUERY(Countries,"select I, max(J) GROUP BY I",1)
```

This will return the below results from the table:

```
Continent       max Population
Africa          173615345
Asia            1385566537
Australia       23342553
Europe          82726626
North America   320050716
South America   200361925
```

Comment: The OP wants the **country**.