# Google Sheets Query by Max Timestamp

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am trying to query a list of timestamps, unique IDs, and data that looks like this:

A - Unique ID

B,C,D,E - Data, but only E is important

F - Timestamp

I want to return A and E where F is the most recent timestamp.

Currently I am using the following query but it returns multiple IDs and timestamps instead of just the MAX timestamps:

```
=QUERY(A:F,"SELECT MAX(F),A,E WHERE E != '' GROUP BY A,E")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51124612/google-spreadsheets-how-to-query-countries-with-max-population-by-continent/51127252#51127252

Comment: Would it be possible to post an example of your dataset?

Comment: Here is a link to sample data. Thanks!
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EBDnaa85Sbna2WYPXqyIDGxrIx84aGvu-WUZ2yymztI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Do you want to return the most recent timestamp per ID, per caller or the most recent timestamp of all ID's/callers?

Comment: Most recent timestamp (Col F) with corresponding notes (Col E) for all unique IDs (Col A)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(Sheet1!A2:A), sort({Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!F2:F }, 3, 0), {1, 2, 3}, 0)))
```

EXPLANATION:

1. Sort() is sorting the ranges descending, based on column F
2. Unique() gets the unique ID's
3. Vlookup() looks for those unique ID's and returns the first three columns {1, 2, 3} of the ranges {Sheet1!A2:A, Sheet1!E2:E, Sheet1!F2:F } (so the values in A, E and F). Because Vlookup() only returns the first match, the data with the most recent timestamp will be returned.

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you so much! If you have a moment to explain how this works I'd appreciate it, but this is fantastic, thank you again!

Comment: Hi @Alex. I added a brief explanation to my answer.